# How to read properties file with IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot service, and I'm using IntelliJ to run it. I have a file call "`application.properties`" in my `resources` folder. I want intelliJ to read that `.properties` file, how do I do that? the only way I get it to use the properties in .properties file is to add them directly to Environment VM Option.

I tried doing things like
`-Dspring.config.location:/src/main/resources/application.properties` but that doesnt work.

Folder Structure:

```
Services
 -src
   -main
     -resources
       -application.properties
 -target
 -pom.xml

@Component
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.org")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Comment: Is the folder resources a resource folder in your module settings?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, it is marked as Resources folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of Spring Boot, you don't have to pass any option when starting boot application.

When Spring boot application loads, it automatically checks if properties file exists in certain locations including `src/main/resources`, `src/main/resources/config`.

If you keep your properties file in these folders, the app automatically picks up the files and register properties. So in your `AppConfig` you don't need `@Component`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@PropertySource`, and `@EntityScan` because `@Configuration` already includes `@Component` which enables `@Value` to work.

I think the problem may arise when you call the property in the constructor of `AppConfig` because when the class is being constructed the `@Value` is not injected yet.

If you want to check if the property value is injected by Spring you can make a small test in the application class such as following

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApppropApplication {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApppropApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println(appConfig.getTestProperty());
    }
}
```

If your problem still exists, it would be great to provide more info (error logs and entire class structure)

Hope this helps! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way for your springboot project to include the properties file would be to import using the annotation "@PropertySource" in your starter class. Please re check your starter class. It should include something like this below

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application-example.properties"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.org")

public class YourProjectLauncher extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Value("${your.db.url}")
private transient String dataSourceUrl;

@Value("${your.db.username}")
private transient String userName;

@Value("${your.db.password}")
private transient String password;

@Value("${your.db.driver-class-name}")
private transient String driverClass;

public static void main(String... args) {

    SpringApplication.run(YourProjectLauncher.class, args);
}
```

Let me know if you have already done this and still facing the issue.

Also it would be best if you add the starter class in your question, that way it is easier to analyse the problem you are facing.

**Note - If you have already done this, please add more information to the question, will be happy to help.**

Comment: I tried but it did not work, however, isn't there is a way to get IntelliJ to read this file by adding something like spring.config.location?

Comment: Can you please add your complete launcher class? Might be able to help better. Also, suggest you edit your question, I think you want the properties file to be accessible by application rather than the IDE you are using. Have you defined the property you want to access using @value? Also, try using the alternate approach where you can auto wire the Environment.